# Pyspark parallelized loop of dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I have a raw Dataframe pyspark with encapsulate column. I need to loop on all columns to unwrap those columns. I don't know name columns and they could change. So I need generic algorithm. The problem is that I can't use classic loop (for) because I need a paralleled code.

Example of Data:

```
Timestamp | Layers
1456982   | [[1, 2],[3,4]]
1486542   | [[3,5], [5,5]]
```

In layers, it's a column which contain other columns (with their own column names). My goal is to have something like this:

```
Timestamp | label | number1 | text | value
1456982   | 1     | 2       |3     |4
1486542   | 3     | 5       |5     |5
```

How can I make a loop on columns with pyspark function?

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reduce function to this. I dont know what you want to do but lets suppose you wanna add 1 to all columns:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def add_1(df, col_name):
    return df.withColumn(col_name, F.col(col_name)+1) # using same column name will update column

reduce(add_1, df.columns, df)
```

Edit:
I am not sure about solving it without converting rdd. Maybe this can be helpful:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

flatF = lambda col: [item for item in l for l in col]
df \
    .rdd \
    .map(row: Row(timestamp=row['timestamp'],
          **dict(zip(col_names, flatF(row['layers']))))) \
    .toDF()
```